# Understanding the Renormalization Group for Entanglement Entropy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, renormalization

I'm trying to understand the renormalization group (RG), and in particular, how it is used to study entanglement entropy (EE) and c-theorems in quantum field theory (QFT). But I'm having trouble with some conceptual aspects that I haven't been able to get around by reading things.

My basic understanding of how RG works in QFT, which I've cobbled together from reading various textbooks and notes on the internet, is as follows: You have a theory specified by a Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ with coupling constants $\{g_i\}$. The coupling constants $\{g_i\}$ that appear in the Lagrangian are called "bare" coupling constants. You can also have a "UV-cutoff" $\epsilon$ that specifies some energy scale $1/\epsilon$ much larger than any scale we care about, and regulates infinities in calculations. Bare couplings $\{g_i\}$ are not things that you can physically measure, but they are related to things that we can measure, which we call "physical" couplings $\{g_i^{phys}\}$. These physical couplings, however, depend on the energy scale $\Lambda$ at which we measure them. The physical couplings are thus functions of the bare couplings and of the energy scale $\Lambda$. When doing calculations of what we expect to measure for these physical couplings, the UV-cutoff $\epsilon$ comes into the calculation. But $\epsilon$ is an artificial parameter, so in order to get the correct calculation of the $\{g_i^{phys}\}$, we need to allow the bare couplings $\{g_i\}$ to be able to vary with $\epsilon$ so that the $\epsilon$ dependence cancels out of the calculations of $\{g_i^{phys}\}$. My understanding is that the "Renormalization group flow" is a description of how the physical couplings $\{g_i^{phys}\}$ change with the energy scale at which you measure them, $\Lambda$.

Okay, I think the above is correct, but here's where I start to get confused: people often talk about the RG flow as a "trajectory in theory space" where at each point along the flow you imagine that you have a different Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ whose coupling constants are the $\{g_i^{phys}\}$ which change as you move along the flow (by changing $\Lambda$), thus changing your theory. But that's not right, is it? The Langrangian's coupling constants are by definition the BARE ones $\{g_i\}$ which are invariant under change of the scale $\Lambda$, right? But people seem to insist on talking about RG flows this way, and say things like "fixed points (sometimes) correspond to Conformal Field Theories (CFTs)" and stuff like that. Is it that they are just talking about a different Lagrangian whose bare couplings ARE the physical couplings (which isn't really the Lagrangian of the theory that you are studying)?

I know that in one particular impelementation of the RG, the Wilsonian approach, you ARE actually changing your action by changing a so-called cutoff $\Lambda$ (note: as seen in comments below, I am not clear on whether to think of the $\Lambda$ in the Wilsonian approach as being a UV-cutoff like $1/\epsilon$ above, as a physical measurement scale as in $\Lambda$ in the above, or neither/both, this is probably the crux of my confusion). Lowering $\Lambda$ is accomplished by functionally integrating over the field modes corresponding to momenta higher than the $\Lambda$ you want to set, which gives you an action that looks like it's based on the same Lagrangian as your old one but with different couplings. Are the couplings in your action in Wilsonian RG actually the physical coupling constants?? Why?? What happened to the bare ones??? Is this method of implementing the RG incompatible with my above understanding of what the RG flow is? Or is there perhaps some sort of duality between [1. fixing your theory/Lagrangian and watching your physical quantities change with $\Lambda$] and [2. fixing a physical quantity and watching your theory/Lagrangian change with $\Lambda$]??

I think that my confusion about these details are contributing to my confusion about how the RG is actually implemented in situations where one uses EE to study c-theorems for QFT, but perhaps I'll describe that later if answers to the above don't solve my problems...

Comment: I think you have it backwards. The physical couplings do *not* depend on the regularization scale. The bare couplings do. In Wilson language, the regularization scale is an arbitrary choice you make, splitting high energy and low energy modes, so no physical quantity should depend on this split. However, making a good choice may have significant practical, computational advantages, like making perturbation theory converge faster.

Comment: So, the way I explained things in the second paragraph, the physical couplings are *not* depending on the regularization scale. The regularization scale is $\epsilon$, and this is distinct from the energy scale $\Lambda$ at which measurements are made. It is natural for the physical measurements to depend on $\Lambda$, for example, you'll get a different measured value for electric charge depending on the CM momentum of the electrons you scatter in your experiment.

Comment: Part of my confusion is about what the Wilsonian cutoff represents. Is it a regularization scale? Is it a measurement scale? Is it neither? Both? How do I explain how the Wilsonian picture works in terms of the setup I have in my second paragraph?

Comment: Normally I think of the renormalization group as the running of the bare couplings with the Wilson scale ($1/\epsilon$ in your language). One reason it is confusing to learn this material is because there is more than one way to think about it. The way I think about, the Wilson scale $1/\epsilon$ is an arbitrary scale you choose when doing the calculation. Then, it is frequently convenient to chose this scale to be of order $\Lambda$, the measurements you are making. For example, 'large logs' in perturbation theory can be resummed in this way.

Comment: I think an excellent reference of this subject is the review by Burgess, https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0701053. For example, one of the subtle points Burgess discusses is that the 'conceptual picture' of renormalization is often described in terms of a Wilson cutoff, but in practical calculations we often use dimensional regularization, in which the momentum integrals go to arbitrarily large scales.

Comment: The way one of my profs in grad school described it was: the renormalization group lets you reorganize perturbation theory between what is 'tree' and what is 'loop'. By making a good choice (like RG scale of order the energy scale of your experiment), you can optimize that split so the tree level tells you a lot about what's going on (i.e., use the coupling constant appropriate for that energy scale)

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your comments, I'll take a look at Burgess' review and see if I can put it together. But to be clear: you're saying that in the Wilsonian approach, the cutoff $\Lambda$ IS the regularization scale, which in a sense is arbitrary and unphysical, but it is helpful to adjust it to match some physically meaningful scale (for example the scale at which you want to measure some physical parameter like electron charge with an accelerator experiment), and so in that sense the Wilsonian cutoff kind of represents both the UV-cutoff *and* a physical scale ?

Comment: I thought we were using $1/\epsilon$ as the Wilson scale and $\Lambda$ as the energy scale of experiments--I am going to stick with that notation. I would say $1/\epsilon$ is (1) an arbitrary choice of scale you make with no a priori logical connection to the scale of experiments $\Lambda$, and (2) it is a cutoff in the sense that momentum integrals only go up to $1/\epsilon$. An important caveat--point (2) depends on the scheme you choose--in dim reg it works slightly differently (see Burgess). Then, yes, you often choose the RG scale $1/\epsilon$ to be close to the measurements you do.

Comment: I really like this question, it speaks to a confusion people often have about what the "couplings" mean. You're right that there is a sense in which we can think about the "true couplings" of the theory as being the bare ones, and then the "renormalised" or "physical couplings" are actually scattering amplitudes related to the bare couplings by some relation. When people talk about a flow in theory space, what they're talking about is an "effective Lagrangian" or an "effective Hamiltonian", which is built by ... (cont)

Comment: (cont) ... writing down a Lagrangian $\mathscr{L}_\mu$ such that if you calculate scattering amplitudes with this Lagrangian, what you'll get at tree level will reproduce the scattering amplitudes *at some scale* $\mu$. One way you can do that is find the relation between the bare and physical couplings through your first procedure, then rewrite the Lagrangian in terms of the couplings at that scale. This is similar to what happens in effective theory, when you have a new looking theory describing the low energy physics ... (cont)

Comment: (cont)... but maybe with different degrees of freedom (you've maybe integrated out some heavy particle). Then you choose some scale $\mu$ at which you match the scattering amplitudes (physical couplings) of the UV and new theories to be equal by choosing a relation between the effective couplings in the new theory and the bare couplings in the original one, and flow down from there. If we've not integrated out some degrees of freedom and the Lagrangian is of the same form, then we're just matching the couplings of $\mathscr{L}_\mu$ and the amplitudes in the UV theory at some scale $\mu$ (cont)

Comment: This is why I don't like it when people say the fine structure constant $\alpha$ depends on some energy scale, and depends on the masses of other particles. Like you say, (assuming QED doesn't need a UV completion, which isn't clear) there's a perfectly valid sense in which there is *a fine structure constant* $\alpha_0$ that is just the parameter in the original Hamiltonian. When people speak of some scale dependent coupling, that is an observable, that often gets written into an effective Hamiltonian constructed to match observables.

Comment: As for the interpretation of the cut-off, one might say that when we define the bare couplings, we're defining what the theory looks like at some scale $\Lambda$. We don't know what happens at infinitely high energy in real life, so most people tend to think of all QFTs as effective theories. At any rate, when we lower the cut off, we're "integrating out" the high energy degrees of freedom. What we're left with is an effective Lagrangian for the degrees of freedom beneath that cut off. The way we get the effective couplings ... (cont)

Comment: (cont) for those new degrees of freedom is by calculating their interactions in the UV theory at scale $\Lambda$, then writing down a Lagrangian whose couplings will reproduce those calculations in the theory without the high energy modes. The reason we might be interested in doing this is that we don't want to keep track of everything at high energies, because our experiments probe things at a lower energy scale. So all the above ways of thinking are equivalent.